# Parsing values from XML into types of Type

Tags: c#, reflection

check this out

```
Type configPropType = configurableProp.getPropertyType();
string attValue = xmlelement.GetAttribute(configurableProp.getName());
configProps[configurableProp.getName()] = attValue;
```

At the point where I am setting the value that got read in from XML it turns out the assigning object needs to be parsed to the correct type for it to work.  I need something like.

```
configProps[configurableProp.getName()] = configPropType.ParseToThisType(attValue);
```

Looked around on msdn but its a very confusing place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you are trying to do is accomplished with something along these lines:

```
configProps[configurableProp.getName()] =
        Convert.ChangeType(attValue, configPropType);
```

Comment: perfect.  here is a challenge, without knowing that - what search terms would find you the answer on msdn?

Comment: I wouldn't use search terms - I'd learn the .NET Framework basics, which would include the `Convert` class. I'd also learn how properties work in .NET, so my code would look like `configurableProp.Name` instead of `configurableProp.getName()`

Comment: That was helpfull John.  I am specifically using functions to get things i dont want saving to XML and reserving the public Getters to save data reflectively.  Unfortunately we don't all have the time to be 46k+

Comment: The [XmlIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) can be used on public fields/properties to instruct the XmlSerializer to ignore them when serializing or deserializing an instance of a class.